# Can I use Cassandra to store objects?

Tags: c#, cassandra

My application works like this.

A database(Mysql) where there is a command. The command is an object(consists of fields many fields like ints and strings). There is a webservice which interacts with the database and get the command from the DB and performs some operation.

The way how I am storing the command into db is by stripping all the fields and inserting them in to the db.

Can I use cassandra in place of mysql and store the command object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to move away from your current solution which involes a relational database? I wouldn't (believe it or not) recommend to change your datastore premature.

If your are experience problems and want to replace your relational database, then I would recommend to investigate [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

If you find Cassandra interesting I would suggest a data model that looks something like this:

```
Commands = { // this is a ColumnFamily (CF)
     commandObject1: { // this is the key to this Row inside the CF
          // now we have an infinite # of columns in this row
          field1: "value1",  
          field2: "value2",
          field3: "value3"
     }, // end row
     commandObject2: {   // this is the key to another row in the CF
          // now we have another infinite # of columns in this row
          field1: "value1",
          field2: "value2",
          field3: "value3"
          field4: "value4",
          field5: "value5"
  },
}
```

(thanks Arin (and his excellent [blog post](http://arin.me/blog/wtf-is-a-supercolumn-cassandra-data-model)) for the Cassandra data model notation)